# C++: Check whether a function changed memory outside some bounds

Tags: c++, gdb

Is there a tool to detect whether a C++ function call changed any memory content *outside* a specific address range?

I know that it is possible to set memory watchpoints using `gdb`; but they only monitor specific locations for changes. In contrast, I want to know whether a function call changed *any* data that it was not supposed to. One could use a memory checker like `valgrind` but as far as I understand such a tool would not catch the case that my function changes memory that *I* know it is not supposed to change but that is allocated by my application.

Comment: Have you looked into Valgrind?

Comment: You mean you want to check if a function modifies a certain valid object that it shouldn't be allowed to modify ? If so, you might want to read up on scope, visibility and const correctness.

Comment: 1. valgrind would be the memory checker option I already noted, right? 2. I know that the function is supposed to manipulate some memory block through pointer access and I want to make sure it modifies only this memory block.

Comment: Have a look at the lackey valgrind tool, you can have it trace memory accesses: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/lk-manual.html